# Regular expression number starting with zero,one or more whitespaces followed by plus or minus

Tags: regex

I have following regex;

```
^(\s)*[+-]?\d+$
```

It fails if input contains multiple whitespaces before first non-whitespace character.
Currently it is working on next examples

```
- :false
-1 :true
+1 :true
```

What I want is same logic if there is 0,1 or more whitespaces at the beginning:

```
: true (empty input string)
    : true (one or more spaces)
  -: false
  -1: true
   +1: true
   235: true
```

Here I'm matching numbers, but on more general scheme I would like same behaviour if there are decimalan, on some special words etc.
So, basicly, I want that my regex match if there is any number of whitespaces at the beginning or empty string, followed by something I wannna match (number, email, special words...)

Comment: Why are you grouping the whitespace? Just use `\s*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the whole pattern optional with an *optional* grouping construct and put the `\s*` *before* the group:

```
^\s*(?:[+-]?\d+)?$
    ^^^        ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VXjbWF/2)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a string
- `\s*`  - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group (if the engine does not support non-capturing groups, remove `?:`) matching....

  - `[+-]?` - an optional (1 or 0 occurrences) `+` or `-` symbols
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `)?` - .... 1 or 0 times
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: It's not working if I enter just one space, it's evaluated to false. It should be evaluated to true if user leaves empty string or enters 1 or more spaces. Semantic is same, user didn't provide any input data, all leading whitespaces should be ignored or evaluated as true

Comment: @Error: You did not provide that test case. I added it to the demo. See the updated answer. If you want to also allow *trailing* whitespace, add `\s*` right after `\d+`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the asterisk in with the \s:

```
^\s*[-+]?\d+$
```

Comment: Empty string evaluates to false, and any number of spaces also evaluates to false.